# ROBOT Framework Exception Handling

Tags: automation, robotframework

How to use **Run Keyword And Ignore Error** in ROBOT Keyword , Please give with example

I have tried to do scrolling by using **Scroll Element Into View    /html/body/section/div[3]/div**

it is scrolling correctly to that point but it is showing it was failed throwing an error of **movetargetoutofboundsexception: message: move target out of bounds** , for handling this I tried to use **Run Keyword And Ignore Error**  but don't know to how to write this in code please help to solve this issue with an example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
Run Keyword And Ignore Error  Scroll Element Into View   /html/body/section/div[3]/div
```

Comment: But it is showing Error in Log File Generation . How to solve this , Because it is working correctly but showing this error .

Comment: I don't think you can fully suppress an error message in RF.